# Как сделать треугольник с границами на css

Tags: css

Добрый день! У меня есть фигура треугольника с границами на css. Но почему-то при масштабировании экрана в браузере эта фигура искажается. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно это исправить, или же выполнить по-другому? Спасибо!

```css
body, html {background:#fff;}
.bar {
  display: block;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
 background-color: #f1f1f1;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
.active-ico {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 margin-left: 50%;
 left: -8px;
 margin-bottom: -1px;
 border: 8px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 10px solid #ccc;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
}
.active-ico:before {
  content: "";
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: -9px;
 margin-left: 50%;
 left: -8px;
 margin-bottom: -2px;
 border: 8px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 10px solid #fff;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar"><div class="active-ico"></div></div>
```

Comment: Что значит "искажается"?

Comment: https://www.screencast.com/t/XFWEBdNS
У меня все выглядит гуд (хром)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно переделать на SVG, у меня при масштабировании не разлазится.

```css
header {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.triangle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -8px;
  bottom: -1px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <svg width=16 height=8 class=triangle>
    <polyline points="0,8 8,0 16,8" />
  </svg>
</header>
```

Comment: Не, я имею в виду, что не искажается, если использовать SVG, а ваш вариант искажается как вы и описали.