# Как сделать окно как в сообщении

Tags: css, svg

Мне нужно сверстать окно в виде такого

[image: Комментарий]

На этой картинке видно что у блока есть "Треугольничек" мне нужно сделать такой средствами `css` или `svg` вот заготовка если что

```css
.message-block {
  width: 300px;
  height: 70px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="message-block"></div>
```

UPD. Не является дубликатом так как мне кажется не относится к [этому вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/659102/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D1%81-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-css)

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/ - возможно это вам поможет...

Comment: А как насчет посмотреть на том элементе, скриншот которого приложили?

Comment: там написано только width и height а про треугольник ничего не сказано

Comment: Не уверен, что это дубликат, CSS он такой, что разные треугольники делаются совершенно по-разному)

Comment: @andreymal в моем ответе такой CSS, что даже SVG :-)

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko который позиционируется всё равно через CSS (-:

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем так можно

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin;0;
  padding:0;
}
.box{
  width:500px;
  margin:auto;
}
.cssarrow {
position: relative;
background: #fff;
border: 3px solid #c2e1f5;
  width:400px;
  min-height:150px;
  float:right;
}
.cssarrow:after,
.cssarrow:before {
right: 100%;
top: 0;
border: solid transparent;
content: " ";
height: 0;
width: 0;
position: absolute;
pointer-events: none;
}
.cssarrow:after {
border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
  border-top:35px solid #c2e1f5;
border-left:35px solid #fff;
margin-top: -3px;
}
.cssarrow:before {
border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
  border-top:30px solid #fff;
border-left:32px solid transparent;
  z-index:100;
  left:-31px;
}
textarea{
  max-width:391px;
  border:none;
  outline:none;
  background:none;
  width:391px;
  min-height:150px;
  padding:10px;
  font-size:20px;
}

img{
  display:block;
  width:80px;
}
p.user{
 float:left;
  margin:-10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p class="user"><img src="http://www.bfl.in.ua/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/w450h4001385925286User.png" alt="">
    <p>
      <div class="cssarrow">
        <textarea placeholder="Describe yourself here..."></textarea>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```css
.message-block { 
  width: 120px; 
  height: 80px; 
  background: green; 
  position: relative; 
  left: 20% 
} 
.message-block:before { 
  content:""; 
  position: absolute; 
  right: 100%; 
  width: 0; 
  height: 0;  
  border-left: 20px solid transparent; 
  border-right: 26px solid green; 
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="message-block"></div>
```

Comment: А с белым фоном и серой обводкой?